# Lacrosse Training Patent

Tags: licensing, wo2013026156

wo2013026156a1 This seems like an interesting concept but there are no drawings.  Will the patent be awarded?  Have prototypes been submitted?  Are they looking for a manufacturer?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Patents. You may have reached us from a "discuss this patent" link on google patents but it is not a direct path to communicate with the inventors or applicants. Only the applicant would know the answer to some of your questions.

Answer (score 1):

This is a PCT (international) application. I am assuming you found this on google patents. Unlike for U.S. patent documents, they do not show the drawings or provide a button to download a PDF. However you will see links to get to this document on Patentscope, the WPIO search site. 
[image]

The summary shows a drawing but to see them all you need to go to the drawing tab. There you will see:
[image]